# Convert single multiple page PDF to a single TIF file

Tags: windows

I want to convert a single PDF document with multiple pages to a single TIF file. The extension must be TIF (with one 'F'). I have Adobe Acrobat Pro

Comment: see here: https://superuser.com/a/287979/171793 . TIF and TIFF are the same in all but name (so rename it if you like), and searching the web for "PDF to TIFF" gets results.

Comment: One TIF which combine in one page all the PDF pages or one multipage TIF?